# Galois theory and Lagrange's method on quintics

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials, quintics

I have just begun studying Galois Theory from [Stewart's book](https://www.amazon.com.br/Galois-Theory-Ian-Stewart/dp/103210158X) and got some questions with some conclusions regarding Lagrange's methods when discussing the quintics. For reference, I will put below part of the discussion in the book:

> Lagrange observed that all methods for solving polynomial equations by radicals involve constructing rational functions of the roots that take a small number of values when the roots αj are permuted. Prominent among these is the expression
> δ = ∏<sub>1≤j<k≤n</sub> (α<sub>j</sub> − α<sub>k</sub>)(1.13)
> where n is the degree. This takes just two values, ±δ: plus for even permutations and minus for odd ones. Therefore ∆ = δ<sup>2</sup> (known as the discriminant because it is nonzero precisely when the roots are distinct, so it ‘discriminates’ among the roots) is a rational function of the coefficients. This gets us started, and it yields a complete solution for the quadratic, but for cubics upwards it does not help much unless we can find other expressions in the roots with similar properties under permutation.
> Lagrange worked out what these expressions look like for the cubic and the quartic, and noticed a pattern. For example, if a cubic polynomial has roots α<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>, α<sub>3</sub>, and ω is a primitive cube root of unity, then the expression
> u = (α<sub>1</sub> + ωα<sub>2</sub> + ω<sup>2</sup>α<sub>3</sub>)<sup>3</sup>
> takes exactly two distinct values. In fact, even permutations leave it unchanged, while odd permutations transform it to
> v = (α<sub>1</sub> + ω<sup>2</sup>α<sub>2</sub> + ωα<sub>3</sub>)<sup>3</sup>
> It follows that u+v and uv are fixed by all permutations of the roots and must therefore be expressible as rational functions of the coefficients. So u + v = a, uv = b where a, b are rational functions of the coefficients. Therefore u and v are the solutions of the quadratic equation t<sup>2</sup> − at + b = 0, so they can be expressed using square roots. But now the further use of cube roots expresses α<sub>1</sub> + ωα<sub>2</sub> + ω<sup>2</sup>α<sub>3</sub> = <sup>3</sup>√u and α<sub>1</sub> + ω<sup>2</sup>α<sub>2</sub> + ωα<sub>3</sub> = <sup>3</sup>√v by radicals. Since we also know that α<sub>1</sub> + α<sub>2</sub> + α<sub>3</sub> is minus the coefficient of t<sup>2</sup>, we have three independent linear equations in the roots, which are easily solved.

I have a couple of questions:

1 - ∆ can be expressed as a rational function as a result of the fundamental theorem on symmetric functions?

2 - Why can u+v and uv be expressed as rational functions?

3 - How the author got the conclusion that α<sub>1</sub> + α<sub>2</sub> + α<sub>3</sub> = -1?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, $\Delta$ is a polynomial in $\alpha_i$ that is invariant under all permutations of them ($\delta$ isn't).
2. An even permutation sends $u$ to $u$ and $v$ to $v$, and an odd one interchanges them.
3. Vieta's formulas (just expand the product $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^3 (t - \alpha_i)$).

Comment: Hmm, got it! So basically, the answer for all questions is Vieta's formulas: every symmetric polynomial can be expressed in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials, which in turn can be expressed as the polynomial coefficients by Vieta's formulas.